# .net data transformation (one object type to another) - looping

Tags: .net

I've been banging my head against this problem for a couple of hours now, if anyone here can offer any pointers I would be grateful. I think I am now snow blinded by this one so a fresh set of brain cells will probably see a really simple solution!

Basically, I have some data I am pulling from a legacy database that needs to be transformed into our stock management system by constructing our own Stock object.

The simplified model is shown below:

```
Public Class Stock
    Public Property Attributes As List(Of StockAttribute)
End Class

Public Class StockAttribute
    Public Property AttributeName As String
    Public Property AttributeValue As String
End Class
```

The source data comes in as this object:

```
Public Class SourceOption
    Public Property OptionName As String
    Public Property OptionValue As String
End Class
```

Some sample data can be constructed using these methods:

```
Function GetSourceList1() As List(Of SourceOption)

    'prepare the source data
    Dim options As New List(Of SourceOption)

    Dim opt As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "Small"

    Dim opt2 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "Medium"

    Dim opt3 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "Large"

    Dim opt4 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Colour"
    opt.OptionValue = "Black"

    Dim opt5 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Colour"
    opt.OptionValue = "Purple"


    options.Add(opt)
    options.Add(opt2)
    options.Add(opt3)
    options.Add(opt4)
    options.Add(opt5)

    Return (options)

End Function


Function GetSourceList2() As List(Of SourceOption)

    'prepare the source data
    Dim options As New List(Of SourceOption)

    Dim opt As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "40"

    Dim opt2 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "41"

    Dim opt3 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "42"


    options.Add(opt)
    options.Add(opt2)
    options.Add(opt3)

    Return (options)

End Function

Function GetSourceList3() As List(Of SourceOption)

    'prepare the source data
    Dim options As New List(Of SourceOption)

    Dim opt As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "Small"

    Dim opt2 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Size"
    opt.OptionValue = "Large"

    Dim opt3 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Colour"
    opt.OptionValue = "Red"

    Dim opt4 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Colour"
    opt.OptionValue = "Blue"

    Dim opt5 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Style"
    opt.OptionValue = "A"

    Dim opt6 As New SourceOption
    opt.OptionName = "Style"
    opt.OptionValue = "B"

    options.Add(opt)
    options.Add(opt2)
    options.Add(opt3)
    options.Add(opt4)
    options.Add(opt5)
    options.Add(opt6)

    Return (options)

End Function
```

So, my "Convert" method needs to take the SourceOption lists and construct Stock lists (with Attributes) as explained here:

Sub Convert()

```
'we need to convert the SourceOption list (in GetSourceList) into a list of Stock, each with a list of StockAttribute. So in the case of GetSourceList1 we would have
'six stock objects, each stock object containing two StockAttribute objects (one for colour and one for size):

'STOCK1 - Attribute1: Size:Small Attribute2: Colour:Black
'STOCK2 - Attribute1: Size:Medium Attribute2: Colour:Black
'STOCK3 - Attribute1: Size:Large Attribute2: Colour:Black
'STOCK4 - Attribute1: Size:Small Attribute2: Colour:Purple
'STOCK5 - Attribute1: Size:Medium Attribute2: Colour:Purple
'STOCK6 - Attribute1: Size:Large Attribute2: Colour:Purple

'in the case of GetSourceList2 we would have three stock objects with only one stockattribute each (for size):

'STOCK1 - Attribute1: Size:40
'STOCK2 - Attribute1: Size:41
'STOCK3 - Attribute1: Size:42

'in the case of GetSourceList3 we would have eigth stock objects with three stockattribute each (for size, colour and style):

'STOCK1 - Attribute1: Size:Small Attribute2: Colour:Red Attribute3: Style:A
'STOCK2 - Attribute1: Size:Large Attribute2: Colour:Red Attribute3: Style:A
'STOCK3 - Attribute1: Size:Small Attribute2: Colour:Blue Attribute3: Style:A
'STOCK4 - Attribute1: Size:Large Attribute2: Colour:Blue Attribute3: Style:A
'STOCK5 - Attribute1: Size:Small Attribute2: Colour:Red Attribute3: Style:B
'STOCK6 - Attribute1: Size:Large Attribute2: Colour:Red Attribute3: Style:B
'STOCK7 - Attribute1: Size:Small Attribute2: Colour:Blue Attribute3: Style:B
'STOCK8 - Attribute1: Size:Large Attribute2: Colour:Blue Attribute3: Style:B
```

End Sub

I do hope that's clear, and any feedback would really be appreciated before I tear all of my hair out!

Thanks
Carl

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find helpful to have a [look here](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) at ValueInjecter. It can help you to convert from object to object by appling some convention you can define.